# Extract nslookup result

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to figure out how I can extract the value of the "Address" of a nslookup command result in an Ansible task. I will always get back 1 ip address in the result:

```
nslookup fs-d12345.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com 10.75.0.2
Server:     10.75.0.2
Address:    10.75.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   fs-d12345.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
Address: 10.75.21.67
```

I need the value **10.75.21.67** to be stored as a var that I can use later in the playbook.

My task would look something like:

```
- shell: "nslookup fs-d12345.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com 10.75.0.2" 
  register: results
```

How do I extract the value of the Address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before reaching for the `command` or `shell` module, always have a look around for alternatives as for common tasks, the Ansible community have often done the heavy lifting for you.

If you can accommodate installing an additional Python package to support, there is already an nslookup (well dig) utility built into Ansible:

```
- set_fact:
    target_ip: "{{ lookup('dig', 'fs-d12345.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com', '@10.75.0.2') }}"
```

The pre-requisite to getting this to work, is you need the dnspython library installed on the machine where this task will be run, e.g.

```
apt-get install python-dnspython
```

or

```
yum install python-dns # (I think ...)
```

If you only want to have to do this on your control machine, but you want to be able to access the looked up data on a remote machine, you could do something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        target_ip: "{{ lookup('dig', 'fs-d12345.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com', '@10.75.0.2') }}"
- hosts: remote_machine
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars['localhost'].target_ip
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. And yes, it is python-dns. I was afraid I would have to come up with some regex pattern filter to extract the address.